# Javascript TypeError with IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm attempting to change an `IFrame` twice with the click of one link. I continuously get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null` whenever that link is clicked.

What this needs to do, is change the source of the `IFrame` on the index page, and then change the source of an `IFrame` on the page that was loaded into the outer `IFrame` on the index page.

```
                    <div class="subjects list-group" target="../../body.html ">
                    <script>
                        function doneLoading() {
                            document.getElementById('index.html#large-column').src = 'body.html';
                        }
                    </script>
                    <a href="subject/English/courses.php"  onclick='doneLoading();'  target='subject' class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">26</span>English</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: `index.html#large-column` what is this

Comment: The ID of the `IFrame` on the index page thats source needs to be changed to `body.html` upon the click of that link.

Comment: check your selector: index.html#large-column something is wrong with it. index is not a vaild html element

Comment: @BlakeStoddard this id wont work..

Comment: Then what is proper way for me to target an `iframe` on another page, but then allow the link to target yet a different `iframe` on a different page?

Comment: You can't interact with other pages (windows) unless you created it from current page (window) and its source is in the same domain. And if you created it from current window, just store it to variable and use like generic window object.

Comment: Here's what it does at the moment: two columns on index page, both iframes. by default, the second iframe on the index page, is loading a page that has two iframes within itself. At the moment, when you click a link within the first iframe on the index page, it'll load the content into one of the iframes on the the page that has been loaded into the second iframe on the main page. I need this to change what the source of the second iframe is on the main page before loading the content into an iframe on the CHANGED page.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach would be to use iframe targeting.

```
<iframe id='content' src='body-default.html'>
<a href='body-en.html' target='content'>English</a>
```

The body-default.html or body-en.html files could contain javascript to update themselves if needed.

Comment: My issue with doing something like that is that the iframes that are being updated are on different pages. I don't understand how I can make one iframe load before it sends the request for the page to be loaded within that page, easily.

Comment: It is simplest to control iframes top down - from your comment you may be better served using some messaging. That way you do not need to worry about timings etc. Some frameworks have good massaging enhancements e.g. dojo, backbone or you could look at pubnub or similar if you want to control screens on different browsers.

Comment: Ok, so I have removed some of the complexity of the problem was having by changing the way I was doing the loading of the index page. (see my last comment on the main question). I removed the first `iframe` and just put the list of links on the index page. Now, is it possible that  when you click a link, it loads a page into the iframe on that page, and then loads a page into the iframe that it loaded? or am i still at a loss here.

Comment: The simplest option is to have the iframe loaded with the first page - you may need to include some default content it it to achieve the result you are looking for.  Then any links outside the iframe can target the already existing iframe in your page.  The main page need only be changed if content needs to be updated outside the iframe.

Comment: I guess the best way for me to show what I need/what is happening is to put up a live example. http://blakestoddard.com/sf/ (Registration process is trying to pull a page which doesn't exist, but that is fine because it simulates what'll happen.)

Select a subject when the page loads and all is well. Select the 'registration process' link and then try to select a subject is when the issues begin.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can look at the problem - is to take the opposite approach - and create a series of pages - and load them in the standard way.   You could use iframes to remove duplicated content e.g. headers and footers if needed.

It is hard to assist further without understanding your use case in more detail.